# Getting IntelliJ warnings everywhere I use the react useContext() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a few contexts I wrote in my project, and everywhere I try to use them I get warnings. So what I did was:

1. Cloned [this example of using react context hooks](https://github.com/Upmostly/react-use-context-hook).
2. Verified that the `useContext(MusicPlayerContext)` line had no warnings in the cloned project.
3. Pasted the context file and the file that consumes it into my project.
4. Verified that I even get the same warning on the `useContext(MusicPlayerContext)` line in my project.

I am sure this is something like a setting or something really simple and/or stupid, I just can't figure it out. The javascript signature check warning seems to be enabled in both projects.

[image]

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: It's a signature mismatch warning. The full warning seems to be some TypeScript monster: Argument type Context<[{}, (function())]> | {_currentValue: any, Consumer: null, _calculateChangedBits: null, $$typeof: symbol, _threadCount: number, _currentValue2: any, Provider: null} is not assignable to parameter type Context<[{}, (function())]>   Type Provider<[{}, (function())]> | null is not assignable to type Provider<[{}, (function())]>     Type ProviderExoticComponent<ProviderProps<[{}, (function())]>> | null is not assignable to type ProviderExoticComponent<ProviderProps<[{}, (function())]>>

Comment: Are you running a Typescript project? Can you include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your `MusicPlayerContext`?

Comment: No it's just a Javascript project. I am trying to figure out how to make a minimal example. Seems like if I could do that, I would know the answer. Still trying...

Comment: FWIW it appears to be some static code analysis. I'm no longer very familiar with Intellij, but do you have any linters running (esLint, sonarLint) or SonarQ, or some setting for this enabled? Does that warning popup provide any suggestions to resolve, ignore, or any links for more details? If you want to, try opening your project in a different IDE to see if it's still flagged? I just cloned that repo locally and I don't see any warnings in `src/hook/useMusicPlayer.js` in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese I have been trying out VS Code lately, and all of these warnings went away.